# Mathematica Use Returned Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm sure this is very simple, but I ask Mathematica for the characteristic polynomial of an equation, as follows:

```
m={
 {0, n, 0, c1},
 {R, 0, 4, c2},
 {0, R, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, R, c4}
}
CharacteristicPolynomial[m,x]
```

Now, I would like to save the returned polynomial as a function, so I can later call it (presumably with something like `f[1]`). Alas, I've been unable to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward.  Simply do this

```
f[x_] = CharacteristicPolynomial[m,x]
```

Note the use of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) (`=`) not [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) which forces `CharacteristicPolynomial` to be evaluated once.  If you used `SetDelayed`, then it would be evaluated every time `f` is evaluated.